# Может ли частица "да" быть подлежащим?

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, частица "да" может быть подлежащим?

Answer (score 5):

Частица ДА выражает согласие при ответе, с тем же значением оно употребляется в функции существительного среднего рода. При этом в предложении ДА может быть подлежащим, сказуемым, дополнением, а также может иметь при себе определение:

Твёрдое, удивлённое, недоверчивое "да". Получить в ответ да. Ни да, ни нет не говорить.  Да - разоружению и миру!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, *частица* не может.

В качестве подлежащего могут использоваться ***только***

- существительные (нарицательные и собственные)
- местоимения
- числительные
- (и ещё кое-что) см., например, [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5).